# Why doesn't my answer to MIT's Introduction to Algorithms PSet 2 Coding Exercise work with their provided tests?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am self-studying MIT's Introduction to Algorithms: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/index.htm

My doubt isn't conceptual. It's more about why a solution that is technically correct and taken out of CSLR fails to work with the specific test code provided in problem set 2. I believe this will be helpful to anyone who in the future tries to self study this course.

In Problem Set 2, there is a coding exercise where one needs to rewrite an array-based priority-queue implementation (a Python class) as a heap-based priority-queue implementation. The Problem Set and solution can be obtained here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/

So here is the solution provided by MIT:

```
class PriorityQueue:
    """Heap-based priority queue implementation."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initially empty priority queue."""
        self.heap = [None]

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of elements in the queue.
        return len(self.heap) - 1

    def append(self, key):
        """Inserts an element in the priority queue."""
        if key is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot insert None in the queue')

        i = len(self.heap)
        self.heap.append(key)
        while i > 1:
            parent = i // 2
            if key < self.heap[parent]:
                self.heap[i], self.heap[parent] = self.heap[parent], key
                i = parent
            else:
                break

    def min(self):
        """Returns the smallest element in the queue."""
        return self.heap[1]

    def pop(self):
        """Removes the minimum element in the queue.

        Returns:
            The value of the removed element.
        """
        heap = self.heap
        popped_key = heap[1]
        if len(heap) == 2:
            return heap.pop()
        heap[1] = key = heap.pop()

        i = 1
        while True:
            left = i * 2
            if len(heap) <= left:
                break
            left_key = heap[left]
            right = i * 2 + 1
            right_key = right < len(heap) and heap[right]
            if right_key and right_key < left_key:
                child_key = right_key
                child = right
            else:
                child_key = left_key
                child = left
            if key <= child_key:
                break
            self.heap[i], self.heap[child] = child_key, key
            i = child
        return popped_key
```

And here is my solution based on what I studied from CSLR:

```
class PriorityQueue:
    """binary min-heap implementation of priority-queue"""
    def __init__(self):
     """Initially empty priority queue."""
     self.heap = []

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of elements in the heap.
        return len(self.heap)

    def parent(self, i):
        return i // 2

    def left(self, i):
        return 2*i

    def right(self, i):
        return 2*i + 1

    def decreaseKey(self, i, key):
        currentKey = self.heap[i]

        if key > currentKey:
            raise ValueError("New key is larger than current key")

        currentKey = key
        parentKey = self.heap[self.parent(i)]
        while i > 1 and parentKey > currentKey:
            currentKey, parentKey = parentKey, currentKey
            i = self.parent(i)

    def append(self, key):
        """Inserts an element in the priority heap."""
        if key is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot insert None in the heap')
        self.heap.append(float("inf"))

        self.decreaseKey(len(self.heap) - 1, key)

    def min(self):
        """The smallest element in the heap."""
        if len(self.heap) == 0:
            return None

        return self.heap[0]

    def pop(self):
        """Removes the minimum element in the heap.

        Returns:
            The value of the removed element.
        """

        if len(self.heap) == 0:
            return None

        min = self.min()
        self.heap[0] = self.heap[-1]
        self.minHeapify(0)
        return min

    def minHeapify(self, i):
        l = self.left(i)
        r = self.right(i)
        leftKey = self.heap[l]
        rightKey = self.heap[r]
        currentKey = self.heap[i]
        heapSize = len(self.heap)
        if l < heapSize and leftKey < currentKey:
            smallest = l
        else:
            smallest = i
        if r <= heapSize and rightKey < smallest:
            smallest = r
        if smallest != i:
            currentKey, self.heap[smallest] = self.heap[smallest], currentKey
            self.minHeapify(smallest)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circuit.py", line 659, in <module>
    sim.run()
  File "circuit.py", line 541, in run
    in_transition[0]))
  File "circuit.py", line 382, in append
    self.decreaseKey(len(self.heap) - 1, key)
  File "circuit.py", line 367, in decreaseKey
    if key > currentKey:
  File "circuit.py", line 300, in __gt__
    return (self.time > other.time or
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Which I interpret as meaning that when I am doing a greater than comparison between attributes of the class PriorityQueue (which I created), it is for some reason using the __gt__ method of a previously defined class, called Transition.

Other than that, when I compare the provided solution to my own (based on CSLR), they are essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: "when I compare the provided solution to my own (based on CSLR), they are essentially doing the same thing" except that MIT solution is not explicitly appending floats to the heap.

Comment: that is true, but I could have appended a really large int and the error would have been the same. I could have appended a string, and it would have been the same. It's using the __gt__ function from another class to compare things, and I don't know why.

Comment: The MIT solution isn't explicitly appending objects of type int, string or any other type.

Comment: You're right. He is appending something (self.heap.append(key)) but he is not specifying what it is. According to @Silmathoron, key is expected to be a Transition object.

Comment: So basically, I was expecting to implement the heap data structure methods with integers as keys. But since the heap actually will contain more complicated objects (Transition object in this case), the solution writes the code in a way that only compares two objects obtained from the heap (because their internal attributes will be compared as specified in their __gt__ methods), never an object with an integer for instance, as I was doing.

Comment: "I was expecting to implement the heap data structure methods with integers as keys." I don't think that's what the assignment says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.heap` is supposed to contain `Transition` objects (which have a `time` attribute).
In your `PriorityQueue.append`, you insert a `float`, which should instead be a `Transition` object with its `time` attribute set to infinity.

```
def append(self, key):
    """Inserts an element in the priority heap."""
    if key is None:
        raise ValueError('Cannot insert None in the heap')
    self.heap.append(Transition(gate, new_output, float("inf")))

    self.decreaseKey(len(self.heap) - 1, key)
```

Edit: maybe I need to precise that though this should solve the problem, I don't think it's how it should be done. The official correction is still better.

Edit2: and of course you need to replace `gate` and `new_output` by reasonable values.

Comment: I think you are right that self.heap was intended to contain Transition objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely related the comparison `i > 1` in your `decreaseKey`. It's very strange to compare against 1 instead of 0, given that the root is at index 0. When the child at 1 is lower than the root, the code will fail to swap them.

The MIT-provided solution has the same weird comparison, but they justify it by putting a dead element at index 0 (notice `self.heap = [None]` and `return len(self.heap) - 1`) so their root really is at 1.